# Assigning value to an iloc slice with condition on a separate column?

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, slice

I would like to slice my dataframe using iloc (rather than loc) + some condition based on one of the dataframe's columns and assign a value to all the items in this slice (which is effectively a subset of the main dataframe).

My simplified attempt:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:21][df['column1'] == 'some_value'] = 1
```

This is meant to take a slice of the dataframe:

- All rows;
- Columns 2 to 20;

Then slice it again:

- Only the rows where column1 = some_value.

The slicing works fine, but equalling this to 1 doesn't work. Nothing changes in df and I get this warning

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I really need to use iloc rather than loc if possible. It feels like there should be a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the error on SO. In short, you should update on one single `loc/iloc`:

```
df.loc[df['column1']=='some_value', df.columns[1:21]] = 1
```